# Flutter Invalid token with phone auth and push notifications

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase-authentication, push-notification

I am using phone auth in my Flutter app. The Android version is working perfectly fine and also iOS version works perfectly fine, until I add push notifications to the project, from Xcode.
After adding push notifications, I start receiving the error *Invalid Token* from Firebase auth at the time of logging in.

> - I am using Flutter **3.7.5**
> - Already added the APN key from the app store to Firebase

So what can be a possible issue and solution to that issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually happens because push notification and background fetch mode are not added.

- Goto signing and capabilities
- Click on add capability
- Select Push notification and Background fetch mode

[image]

I think it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i have already added these 2 parameters in my code, but still facing this error.